# Sitecore The path "{E18F4BC6-46A2-4842-898B-B6613733F06F}" was not found

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

After fresh deployment I'm getting the error below:

```
[ArgumentNullException: The path "{E18F4BC6-46A2-4842-898B-B6613733F06F}" was not found.
Parameter name: Item]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.AssertItem(Item item, String path) +113
   Sitecore.Data.DeviceRecords.DoGetAll() +61
   Sitecore.Data.DeviceRecords.GetAll() +36
   Sitecore.Data.Items.DeviceItem.FindBestMatch(Database database, HttpContextBase httpContext) +45
   Sitecore.Data.Items.DeviceItem.ResolveDevice(Database database, HttpContextBase httpContext) +148
   Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.DeviceResolver.Process(HttpRequestArgs args) +240
   (Object , Object[] ) +59
   Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object[] parameters) +36
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +365
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +158
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs ) +459
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +165
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

I tried to solve and googled as well. Found this below but didn't help:
http://www.sitecoredevelopment.com/markursino/2015/december/sitecore-publish-deletes-content

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

This item is a `/sitecore/layout/Devices` item. It means that your database is incomplete.

If it's only for end users (not in Sitecore editing part), it means that this item has not been published for some reason.

If this is for editing as well, it means that your master database is corrupted. You can try to migrate this single item to your master database, but probably there will be more items missing.

Comment: Thanks Marek, I also noticed that icon is missing for quiet a few items on content tree and also some menu items. Not sure what happened.

Comment: Do you use some kind of tool for Sitecore items sync between environments? Unicorn? TDS?

Comment: TDS but had no issue with local env.

Comment: OK, I changed the connection string for master DB to different instance i.e. DEV. But still same issue. The DEV sitecore which points to this DEV DB works fine. I'm now confused..

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question with probably a different cause from mine (since Sitecore 10 wasn't out at that time), but if you ended up here like me after seeing this error after upgrading your Sitecore into 10+, the problem is probably with the dataProvider configuration.

Previously (prior to v10) Sitecore used the database to store sitecore items, now it uses resource files. The configuration also look a bit different.
But if you're upgrading you may have some old configurations that need to be updated which are overriding the use of the resource files.

You might have something similar to this:

```
<dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">
   <prefetch role:require="ContentManagement or Standalone" hint="raw:AddPrefetch">
     <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config" />
     <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Core.config" />
   </prefetch>
</dataProvider>
```

You will have to update this to:

```
<dataProvider type="Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.CompositeDataProvider, Sitecore.Kernel">
  <param desc="readOnlyDataProviders" hint="list">
    <protobufItems type="Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.ReadOnly.Protobuf.ProtobufDataProvider, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <filePaths hint="list"> 
      <filePath>$(dataFolder)/items/$(id)</filePath>
      <modulesFilePath>/sitecore modules/items/$(id)</modulesFilePath>
    </filePaths>
  </protobufItems>
  </param> 
  <param desc="headProvider">
<dataProvider ref="dataProviders/main" param1="$(id)">  
  <prefetch hint="raw:AddPrefetch">    
    <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Common.config" />
    <sc.include file="/App_Config/Prefetch/Master.config" />
  </prefetch>
</dataProvider>
```

Comment: Answering an old Question with "to recent" content is a great idea as you helped my out by doing so :-)

Answer (score 1):

this mean that device item not exist , try to take it from another instance and install it, this fix the issue with me.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this issue today, and it was during the installation of the SXA to another environment. Basically, it was because SXA always includes the device item under layout if you picked 'include templates', 'include media' or 'include layout', hence use merge-merge installation option instead of overwrite.

Btw, I am using Sitecore v9.0.1 and SXA v1.6. It may be irrelevant to the context of this post but somewhat the same error I encountered.

Lastly, another way to revert back the device folder including siblings such as renderings and sublayouts if deleted is to transfer it from web database to master database via control panel.

Note that packaging your layouts folder and install it as a normal way of installing packages won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple fix, although if you're running into this issue, there are likely to be other issues. Start with this:

1. Navigate to `/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx?db=web&lang=en&id={EB2E4FFD-2761-4653-B052-26A64D385227}` (update the params as necessary)
2. Click the "Delete" button to delete the "Layout" item and all of its children in the web DB
3. Go back to the Content Editor
4. Verify that the "Devices" item has a version in the language that you need
5. Republish the Layout item `{EB2E4FFD-2761-4653-B052-26A64D385227}` and all of its children
6. Consider reindexing that portion of the tree if you still have issues